# How can I check whether or not Motion & Fitness is enabled on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, core-motion

I know how to check whether or not Motion & Fitness is available on the user's device using CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable(), and I know how to check whether or not Motion & Fitness permission has been granted to the app using CMMotionActivityManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorized, but I need to be able to check whether or not the user has Motion & Fitness enabled on their device via their Settings -> Privacy -> Motion & Fitness. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You want `CMMotionActivityManager.authorizationStatus() == .restricted` although the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clauthorizationstatus/restricted) could be clearer around this.

Additionally from my testing the `authorizationStatus` stays `restricted` until the App is re-launched which confuses things further. You will need to inform users to re-launch the App after toggling the setting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).